# How to take user input after command and save it as variable discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

can someone tell my why my code is not working?
i want the bot to message me what i type after !test.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Game
command_prefix = "!"
client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('prihlaseno za {0.user}'.format(client))

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *, mess):
    await ctx.send(mess)
client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix `client` with `bot`. Use one or the other (`bot` is typically used). Then change your code to fit one of these. For example, if you pick `bot`, rename `@client.event` to `bot.event` and change `client.run` to `bot.run`.

You are also needlessly importing the `Bot` class again when you have already imported it from `discord.ext.commands`. I'm also not sure what `discord.Game` is at the end of your imports.